# How to store the internal error message in a txt file?

Tags: 16.04, package-management

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.
If you notice further problem, try restarting the computer 

send an error report to help fix problem

show details / continue
```

This is the kind of message I am getting on my ps, after each reboot. I need to store the details so that I can work on them, is here any way to track those errors and store it in a text file, say,  system_error.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Simply press the 'Details' button. this opens a text field with all information about the bug/error, then simply copy and paste to gedit for example, but every other text editor will do as fine as gedit.

[image: https://askubuntu.com/a/918244]
<sup>Image is just an example message I found [here on the site](https://askubuntu.com/a/918244) in an deleted post.</sup>

You may want to give it a bit time to collect all information tho.

Comment: no we cant select them since it does not open as text field